# php mkdir() permissions denied mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, mkdir

This seems to be a common problem, but I can't seem to find the exact answer I'm looking for.
I'm running XAMPP on OSX, and in my web app am trying to allow an admin to create a directory if none exists for a new year. So, under htdocs/mywebapp/images, if a directory doesn't exist for, say, 2012, then mkdir() and begin uploading files to that directory.

Running ls -l from the mywebapp directory shows that the images directory is created as

```
drwxr-xr-x   18 myusername  admin    612 Feb 12 17:32 images
```

so the first thing I tried was

```
sudo chmod 0775 images
```

which didn't help. Looking at the httpd.config file shows that the user/group is defined as www:www so I tried changing the owner/group to that:

```
sudo chown www:www images
```

which results in, as expected:

```
drwxrwxr-x  18 _www      _www     612 Feb 12 17:32 images
```

but, again, I get the Permission denied error. So, I'm at a loss as to what my next step is.
The php code I'm using to get to this point is here:

```
$directory_self = dirname(__FILE__);
$base_image_path = $directory_self . '/images/'; // outputs "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mywebapp/images/"
$year = '2012';
$image_path = $base_image_path . $year . '/'; // outputs "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mywebapp/images/2012/"
if(!file_exists($image_path)){
    mkdir($image_path, 0775);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to check real process owner:

```
  $processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
  echo($processUser['name']);
```

Comment: ah... it shows "nobody". So I should chown to nobody:[group???]... but I'm curious as to why the process owner would be nobody if the user is defined as www in the config file. Also, how would I find the real process user in the Terminal? Thanks!

Comment: I see that if I run $processGroup = posix_getgrgid($processUser['gid']);
echo $processGroup['name']; the group is "nobody"... so I'll try that now. And, yes, it worked and I was able to mkdir().

Comment: Another question is why specifying the permissions using mkdir(filepath, 0755) is no different than mkdir(filepath, 0775)... both show drwxr-xr-x after the directory is created.

Comment: there is one remark in official docs, take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php. Abous umask.