# How to let php get mkdir() access?

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I have a piece of code as follows in php

```
$success = mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
if ($success === false) {
    $this->warn("Failed creating target directory [$dir]. Closing appender.");
    $this->closed = true;
    return false;
                }
```

When I run this I get an error

```
mkdir(): Permission denied in /<mypath>
```

How do I give access to mkdir(). I am running macOS 12(MOnterrey)

Comment: The issue is not access to the command that is denied. But to create that folder in the file system. So you need to check the remissions of the folder you want to create that folder in. Most likely you forgot to make it writable for the php process.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you look into your file system, find out what the actual permissions of that folder are and adjust them such that the php process has write access. So you first want to find out under what user and group account that php process operates. That depends on what you are doing, which I don't know.

Comment: What is in $dir

Comment: @arkascha I have gone into all folders and allowed read and write privileges for all users- (system, admin, myuser) and I still get the error. I ran the command echo exec('whoami'); and I get my own name and when I check command+i for the permissions, my name is the owner and has read and write permissions

Comment: See who _owns_  the php process. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9557646/1685196), it might be different from what you suspect.

Comment: I added the line and I get my name as the response. But for my name, I have all permissions. Read and Write.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the process has read and list (execution) permission for all folders leading from root (`/`) to the folder you want to create a folder in.

Comment: And you should check if you have any php extension installed that might block access to parts of the file system. Take a look at the `phpinfo()` method for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest using the php safe library, see https://github.com/thecodingmachine/safe - it overrides php's default methods with rewritten methods that throw exceptions. This is safer exception handling. If you use safe, you can surround the `mkdir` method with a try-catch.

It looks like your php doesn't have the right write permissions to create the folder. Maybe you must set the correct permissions with `chmod`.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP checked and what apparently is _not_ the issue, according to the comments to the question.